# Application of Poisson Integral Formula and Fourier Series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I'm working through an exercise in Chapter 4.2 of the PDE book by Robert McOwen. I have derived that when $n=2$ and $a=1$, the Poisson integral formula can be represented by

$$u(r,\theta)=\frac{1-r^2}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{g(\phi)d\phi}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

Now, I'm trying to verify that

$$r^k\cos k\theta=\frac{1-r^2}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos (k\phi)d\phi}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

where $k$ is an integer and $0\leq r < 1$.

I've previously derived that we can find $u(r,\theta)$ by the Fourier series representation

$$u(r,\theta)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n(a_n \cos n\theta + b_n\sin n\theta)$$

But, I'm not sure why this implies that

$$r^k\cos k\theta=\frac{1-r^2}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos (k\phi)d\phi}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

Is there a property of Fourier series that I can reference to show that

$$g(\phi)=\cos (k\phi)$$

and that

$$u(r,\theta)=\frac{1-r^2}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos (k\phi)d\phi}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $g(\theta)$ is the boundary condition for your PDE: that is, you want to find a function $u(r,\theta)$ solving
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\Delta u = 0& \text{in } B(0,1)\\
u(1,\theta) = g(\theta)&\\
\end{array}\right.\tag{*}$$
The function $u$ given by the Poisson formula is the unique solution to the problem, so if we have any function solving $(*)$, then that function must be equal to the Poisson integral.

In particular, we notice that the function $u(r,\theta) = r^k\cos(k\theta)$ solves $(*)$ with $g(\theta) = \cos(k\theta)$ (this is just a computation).  But, since the solution is unique, this means that
$$r^k\cos(k\theta) = \frac{1-r^2}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(k\phi)}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)}\;d\phi$$

---

Notice in particular that we aren't declaring $g(\theta) = \cos (k\theta)$ *always*.  What it is varies from problem to problem.  However, *if* $g(\theta) = \cos(k\theta)$, then $u(r,\theta) =r^k \cos(k\theta)$ is the only solution to the PDE $(*)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $g(\theta)$ is the function satisfying the following property: $\Delta_2 u = u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r}u_r + \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta} = 0$ and $u(1,\theta) = g(\theta) = \cos(k\theta)$.

Substituting $u(r,\theta) = r^k \cos(k\theta)$ we see that it satisfies the hypothesis above. So we can let $u$ and $g$ be as such.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $u(r,\theta) = r^k \cos(k\phi)$ though? The original form is phrased with the variable $\theta$ instead of $\phi$.

Comment: You are right. But it doesnt change the answer, since i just written theta as phi.

Comment: It seems correct. Although, you still need to substitute $g(\theta)=cos(k\phi)$ into the final form of $u(r,\theta)=\frac{1-r^2}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos (k\phi)d\phi}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)}$. This seems troubling.

Comment: It may help to post the full question from the text. Since the Poisson formula is what it is.